# ASP.NET Core - HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is null in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using a custom `CookieAuthentication` in ASP.NET Core and I have these three methods in my HomeController:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Index()");
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(User.Identity.Name);
        }
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet("getlastdisposal")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult GetLastDisposal()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("GetLastDisposal()");
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(User.Identity.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("IT IS NULL");
        }
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet("getchartdata")]
    public JsonResult GetChartData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The log I am getting back is this:

```
...
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
      Index()
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
      admin
...
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
      GetLastDisposal()
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
      IT IS NULL
...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (null).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was challenged.
```

Looking at this, it seems like `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` becomes null after the first successful authorization (before `Index()`), which makes the authorization before `GetChartData()` fail. Any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: **Not tested:** try to explicity make the Method `GetLastDisposal`: `[AllowAnonymous]` as well as `[Authorize]`

Comment: I have tried that, I get the same error when I set it to `[Authorize]`. I get no errors when I set it to `[AllowAnonymous]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core authentication cookie only received once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306931/asp-net-core-authentication-cookie-only-received-once)

Comment: @A.Savva OP made no mention of using React and your suggested duplicate's answer is regarding the use of React

Comment: @ctorx true, but in both cases it was the same issue, I forgot to include `{ credentials: 'same-origin' }` in the client code. That does not have to do with React