# ASP.NET Core authentication cookie only received once

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, session-cookies

I am developing an application with ASP.NET Core and I am using a custom Cookie Authentication. My `CookieAuthenticationOptions` are:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/unauthorized/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

The cookie is created just fine and I can see it in the browser settings throughout the whole time I am running the application. This is my `HomeController` class:

```
public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env,
    IAntiforgery antiforgery,
    IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings,
    TerminalDbContext terminalContext,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor)
{
    _env = env;
    _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    _appSettings = appSettings;
    _terminalContext = terminalContext;
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>();
    _httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;


    _logger.LogInformation("Cookie coming");
    var cookies = _httpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"];
    if (cookies != null)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(cookies.Length.ToString());
        _logger.LogInformation(cookies.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
    _logger.LogInformation("THE COOKIE IS NULL");
    }
}
```

And this is how I sign in the user:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginInfo.Username),
        new Claim("DbName", loginInfo.Terminal.SesamDbName),
    };

var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "password");

ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
await _httpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

I am running the application and more than one instances of the `HomeController` are created, since I have `HttpGet` methods that return a `JsonResult` that is needed for the view.

The first time the application tries to `[Authorize]` (for the `Index()` method), it finds the cookie and authenticates and authorizes fine. The second time it tries to `[Authorize]` (for an `HttpGet` method that returns a `JsonResult`) it doesn't find the cookie, even though it is there in my browser's settings. This is the log I get, to illustrate this:

```
...
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
      Cookie coming
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
      347
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
  CfDJ8GSLZENXaNpNrtmz2DAt9joqJ6CEHpCFbJdbNxbQYjjoQmd4naOI0L0krNMSQdVhqPRP9tJJMMIRayc5ILRQMcJQWNZ0T9Fjuk7Qxg65wPP7SR43UZxwy6vGQ7_qeSp44gYLLe4NGEalhXynZxmD-jywqL4VJZ5y4OwpsEKLx-VVT03xAlt54J_qQk_O4wjwLQiZBpAVTFKUWN4u7H8yd_rwMTIGBPu21t5n35To9bTQU5677xNxiEFap3ukuxO4p-OxVakXqShy2Xk_vYDAvv_XFV6jgNcy4ZiCRB8VUhXGcNr205h4X0-O7JHB8mYbc13aZLmrAwvG5DWTBd3_OCo
...
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
      Cookie coming
info: Server.Controllers.HomeController[0]
      THE COOKIE IS NULL
```

Why does this happen? What can I do about it?

Comment: Are you sure you are making the request via HTTPS in _both_ cases?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: I've figured out what the problem was, thanks for the help, I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: What was the problem? I notice whether I use cookies or basic authentication the User property on the HTTP context doesn't hydrate after about 60 seconds of inactivity.

Comment: @ScottWilson I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with the backend. I am using React in the front-end and the problem was that `fetch()` was not passing the cookies to the back-end for the `GET`methods. I just had to set `{ credentials: 'same-origin' }` to `fetch()` in order to send the cookies with the request. Thanks for all the help.